# How to get current user Id and user claim in any Class without pass by controller asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a dynamic menu for all user dependence on user claims.
I have three types of user claims Admin, Employee, and Manager. Now I need to get user policy in a class. So how can I get it?

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    public MainMenuModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager; 
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
```

I try to catch claim using this code.

```
        var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        var claims = _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Result);
```

Show the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Can I access the user's claims in class?

Comment: You need to show us how you are configuring this in Startup.cs, and explain what is calling your MainMenuModel. Also, why are you using user.Result instead of await?

Comment: 'options.AddPolicy("CompanyAdmin", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new CompanyAdminRequirement());
                });

'
'services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CompanyAdminRequirementHandler>();'

I have create handler class

Comment: You need to show us how you are configuring asp.net identity in your startup class

Comment: Code is too much, that's why its stored here https://codeshare.io/mpojr4

please see it.

Comment: If you have not initialized the object variable, so it doesn't point to anything. In this case, if you access the members of this type of object, it will cause the situation. Where is your mistake?

Comment: May I get any example access user Id or anything?

Comment: I need current user Id

Comment: private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public MainMenuModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void GetUserId()
        {
            var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        }